# MySQL 5.7: Order by left-joined one-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

### Database

```
mysql> DESCRIBE filtercategories;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| position | tinyint(4)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE tags;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| slug    | varchar(64)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| name    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| color   | varchar(7)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| visible | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE filtercategories_tags;
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| filtercategory_id | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id            | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| position          | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Goal

To return a LIST of `filtercategories` ordered by **position**, the left-joined tags should be ordered by **position** as well.

---

So far trying smth like:

```
SELECT
  fc.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS tagNames
FROM filtercategories fc
LEFT JOIN (filtercategories_tags fc_t, tags t)
ON (
  fc_t.filtercategory_id = fc.id AND
  t.id = fc_t.tag_id
)
GROUP BY fc.id
ORDER BY fc.position
```

Problem is that MySQL would not allow to use `ORDER BY fc_t.position`:

> ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'foo_db.fc_t.position' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: MySQL complains for good reason. `fc_t.position` can have multiple values per group. You didn't say which one you want to use for ORDER BY.

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match the query. The error message says `fc_t.position`, but the query says `fc.position`.

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` is a big NO.

Comment: No other dbms will run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the left-joined tags should be ordered by **position** as well.

Then you should use an `ORDER BY` clause within `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT
  fc.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(t.name ORDER BY fc_t.position) AS tagNames
FROM filtercategories fc
LEFT JOIN filtercategories_tags fc_t ON fc_t.filtercategory_id = fc.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = fc_t.tag_id
GROUP BY fc.id
ORDER BY fc.position
```

I also fixed your JOIN syntax. Please don't mix explicit JOINs with comma joins in one query. This is hard to understand and debug.

Comment: `ORDER BY` INSIDE `GROUP CONCAT` was the key. Btw, the comma joins are part of Oracle's MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html.

Comment: @Oleg It's an example to show the different but equivalent syntax. It doesn't mean that you should use it. I'd use neither of the two queries. But it's up to you.